Show that the function $f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x\neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$ has no Maclaurin's series
Show that the function $$f(x)=\begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} & x\neq 0, \\ 0 & x=0 \end{cases}$$ has no Maclaurin's series expansion but the function has derivative of all order everywhere.
We have
$e^{-1/x^2}=1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2!x^4}-\frac{1}{3!x^6}+\frac{1}{4!x^8}+...$
How to show that?

Well, it has a Maclaurin series, it just doesn't converge to $f$ in any open interval around $0.#

@ThomasAndrews https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/please-sir-solve-using-easy-method-helpful-explain-q106051330

Your series is Laurent series! Maclaurin (or Taylor) series cannot have negative power of $x$.

@AngaeMT Would you please solve it
